# view controller for dictionary/defining words in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I saw a couple weeks ago there is a view controller for a dictionary in iOS 5 that we can pass in a word and it will provide the definition of it. I can't seem to find the documentation again in apple doc's, does anyone know what the name is?

Comment: Check my answer with a link to the documentation and a sample code on how to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to use the Dictionary service provided by [UIReferenceLibraryViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIReferenceLibraryViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

```
// Create the view controller
UIReferenceLibraryViewController *reference = 
  [[[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:@"Word"] autorelease];

[self presentModalViewController:reference animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: +1. It may also be a good idea to use `+dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:` to determine if the dictionary even has a definition for that term before creating and displaying an instance of `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`.